# How to implement C macro with assert

Tags: c, macros, assert

I work on a C project, it implements a kind of polymorphism by using macros

```
void method1Instrumentation(void*);
bool method2Instrumentation(void*);
bool method3Instrumentation(void*);

#define method1(arg) method1Instrumentation(arg)
#define method2(arg) method2Instrumentation(arg)
#define method3(arg) method32Instrumentation(arg)
```

For each of `method1Instrumentation, method2Instrumentation, method3Instrumentation` there are several implementations. Based on internal configuration, compiler "chooses" the appropriate function.
I (probably) can`t change the given design.
But I need to add `asserts` to `method*`.

is works fine

```
#define method1(arg) assert(arg == NULL) method1Instrumentation(arg)
```

doesn`t work (compilation problems)

```
#define method2(arg) assert(arg == null) method2Instrumentation(arg)
```

The problem occurs since the original code has following calls

```
if(method2(arg))
{
}
```

How should I add an `assets` following the limitations I have?

Comment: Did you intend to declare `method1Instrumentation` 3 times? Or should they be 2 and 3?

Comment: What is `null`, should that be `NULL`?

Comment: "How should I add an `assets`?" should be `assert`.

Comment: What should happen in the case of `if` statement if `arg == null`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asserting that the arg is **not** null?

Comment: There are so many false claims in this question! Probably all from typos, though. But still, this wastes our time and/or it forces us to make guesses, which means we could be giving you incorrect and/or incomplete responses. Please proofread what you post!

Comment: If you just want polymorphism, you should look at using C11's `_Generic`.

Comment: Put the semicolon between assert call and method.. function call. And replace null with NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to combine the `assert` and function call into a single expression. Also, wrap it in parentheses to prevent problems with operator precedence when combining it with other operators.

```
#define method1(arg) (assert(arg != NULL), method1Instrumentation(arg))
```

Comment: wouldn't it be && since the methodXInstrumentation is returning bool and no second argument is expected?

Comment: @Mario The Spoon, You mean instead of the comma? No, because `assert` returns `void`.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon The return value of `assert()` isn't specified.

Comment: ok did not notice, but would then not the compilation of the if( method2(xxx) also fail?

Comment: No, why would it? The return value of the left operand of the comma operator isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

TO work a little against the macro ugliness I would suggest something along these lines:

**Edited to use assert() as pointed out in comment;**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool method1( void* data );
bool method2( void* data );

typedef bool (*methodPointer)(void*);

bool assertAndCall( void* data, methodPointer );

#define call1( arg )  assertAndCall( arg, method1 )
#define call2( arg )  assertAndCall( arg, method2 )


bool method1( void* data )
{
    printf("method1\n");
}

bool method2(void* data )
{
    printf("method2\n");
}

bool assertAndCall( void* data, methodPointer mp )
{
    assert( arg == null );

    mp( data );
}


int main()
{
    call1( "test ");
    call2( "test" );
    call1( NULL );

    return 0;
}
```

I know, still a lot of macros and there are better solutions, but I wanted to play around,,,

Comment: You're not triggering whatever error the standard `assert()` macro normally produces. You're also not dependent on the `NDEBUG` macro like `assert()` is.